# How to create a route with 5 to 10 meters added to the outer area

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I create route a like below image? My code shows the normal route but I want a route like the below image, where it adds 5 to 10 meters to the outer area; also, is it possible?

```
function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
                service.route({
                    origin: origin,
                    destination: destination,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                    avoidTolls: true
                }, function (response, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        display.setDirections(response);
                    }
                    else if (!destination || destination == '') {
                        alert('Please enter destination for directions');
                    }
                    else if (!origin || origin == '') {
                        alert('Please enter origin for directions');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
                    }
                });
            }
```

i get below code but i can't understand how to add this code in my  code ,

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      console.log(response); // to inspect in the console
      // grab the polyline that contains the route to draw

      var route = response.routes[0].overview_polyline;
      var polyOptions = {
              strokeColor: '#AA4588',
              strokeOpacity: .8,
              strokeWeight: 8,
              map: map,
              path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(route)
       };
        // show the polyline on the map
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);

       // use the property bounds to change zoom
        map.fitBounds(response.routes[0].bounds);

       // more things here
    }
  });
}
```

my current map that i was draw but i want second one
[my current map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWBlE.png)

[image: Route map]

Comment: Could you clarify what you need help with?

Comment: i want below image like route but my code show normal route

Comment: What do you mean by 'outer area', specifically? Outer area of what?

Comment: i want like below image....i think this is outer area of route

Comment: is that a mockup, or did you find a website that shows the route with a ribbon like that?

Comment: yes i found one site.....this image

Comment: I see now it's a local/router ip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+maps+polyline